# I have one code which read data from csv file in selenium java and I want to do if any cell is empty then skip this cell and read next automatically

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I wrote a code in selenium java which read data from CSV file and type in my website automatically. But I want this code to be like if any cell is empty then it automatically skips this cell and read next automatically.

```
 CSVReader reader = null;
    int numberOfRows = 0;


    try {
        reader = new CSVReader ( new FileReader ( Excelpath ) );
        String[] cell = reader.readNext ();
        int i = 0;
        userid[i] = cell[1];
        passwrd[i] = cell[2];
        second[i] = cell[3];
        while (( cell = reader.readNext () ) != null) {


            if (i >= 3) {
                distributor[ i - 3 ] = cell[ 2 ];
                site[ i - 3 ] = cell[ 3 ];
            }
            i++;
        }


        numberOfRows = i - 1;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
```

I expect the output to be like if any empty cell in CSV file then it will skip automatically and read the next cell

Comment: How is this question related to `selenium`?

Comment: I gave the only shortcode which shows only CSV file reader

Comment: You can collect all the strings from csv file and than delete strings with zero lenght.

Comment: What about extending your code to match that requirement?